# Executing command on batch file with conditions

Tags: batch-file, cmd, routes

I need execute two commands on Windows 7 startup (with .bat file):

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201
route -p add 192.168.4.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.5.201
```

If first route doesn't exists on system - .bat file doesn't executes properly. First command executes on infinity loop.
How can i check if this route exists and then execute first command?

P.S. or maybe there is another way to do it without .bat file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the infinite loop here; for me it just exits with an error.

But you can check for a particular route with

```
route print 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201
```

However, that alone won't be enough as the exit code of `route` is always 0. So you have to pipe through `findstr`:

```
route print 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201 | findstr 192.168.5.201
```

Afterwards you can either check `errorlevel`:

```
if not errorlevel 1 route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201
```

or chain the command:

```
route print 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201 | findstr 192.168.5.201 && route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201
```

Comment: What should i do with "route print 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201 | findstr 192.168.5.201"? Pass it to "IF" statement? If i simply paste it to .bat file it stucks on this step.

Comment: Either that line and the `if` that follows or the last line I gave you.

Comment: I was so stupid). My fault was that the name of the file was "route.bat"). route print | findstr 192.168.5.201 && route delete 0.0.0.0 192.168.5.201 works just fine. thx